# Customizing c-mode indentation behavior in Emacs 24.4

Tags: indentation, emacs24.4, cc-mode

Before Emacs 24.4, indentation in `c-mode` happened after typing things like `;`, `,` and so on and I like this behavior.

But in Emacs 24.4, `c-mode` also indents on <kbd>RET</kbd>. This causes a lot of problems for me because if I want to insert a blank line, I need to press <kbd>RET</kbd> and then delete any spaces or tabs that `electric-` inserts.

So I would like to disable indent on <kbd>RET</kbd>, but keep all other electric-indent functionality, like indent on `;`.

How can I achieve this?

I tried calling `(electric-indent-local-mode -1)` in `c-mode` hooks,
but this disabled not only indent on <kbd>RET</kbd>, but also indent on `;`, `,` and so on.

Comment: FWIW, the way I do it is that I hit RET either at the beginning of the next line, or at the of the previous line, depending on whether I just want to insert a blank line, or intend to actualy type text after thi RET.

Comment: FWIW, the [news for release 24.4](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/news/NEWS.24.4) notes that `electric-indent-mode` is now enabled by default; `RET` now inserts a newline and indents, while `C-j` inserts a newline but does not indent (basically swapping the functionality of `RET` and `C-j` from previous versions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could rebind `RET` to `electric-indent-just-newline` like this:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
          (lambda() (local-set-key (kbd "<RET>") 'electric-indent-just-newline)))
```

Comment: Please don't quote your lambdas.

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks!  I removed the redundant quote.

Answer (score 4):

You want to do:

```
 (add-hook 'c-mode-hook
           (lambda ()
             (setq-local electric-indent-chars
                         (remq ?\n electric-indent-chars))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks more right solution, then rebinding RET.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply use `C-j` to insert empty lines on Emacs 24.4?

Comment: No, pressing enter is conditioned reflex, why I should change my head firmware, instead of computer firmware

Comment: Fortunately you're not a computer, I believe. :)

Comment: @mdallastella: this response would probably be better as a comment on the question rather than an answer to it.

Comment: Drat: and by "response," I mean your original answer, not your commented response to OP's comment.

Comment: You're right, but I thought the op didn't know about C-j.