# ChangeLog mode indentation breaks when pressing return

Tags: indentation

For personal notes, I create `ChangeLog` files of the following format:

```
2015-01-27+0000  Felix E. Klee  <felix.klee@inka.de>

    * Today, I asked my first question on emacs.stackexchange.com:

      - My question is about issues with ChangeLog files.

Local Variables:
fill-column: 79
fill-indent-according-to-mode: nil
coding: utf-8
add-log-time-format: (lambda () (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d%z"))
End:
```

The problem: After upgrading to version 24.4.1, when I press return at the end
of `files.`, then the line changes identation depth:

```
    * Today, I asked my first question on emacs.stackexchange.com:

    - My question is about issues with ChangeLog files.
```

*How do I prevent identation from changing in that case?*

Already I tried specifying buffer local variables, to no avail:

```
adaptive-fill-regexp: "\\s *\\|\\s -"
paragraph-start: "\\s *$\\|\f\\|^\\<\\|\\s -$"
```

FYI after upgrading to Emacs 23, I had another ChangeLog indentation
[issue](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2009-09/msg00738.html), which IIRC I may have solved by editing `changelog-mode` source
code. I would like to avoid that this time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable auto-indentation of new lines?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5939/how-to-disable-auto-indentation-of-new-lines)

Comment: To what command is `return` bound (check with `C-h k <return>`)? The default bindings changed with 24.4, which effectively swapped the bindings for `return` and `C-j`.  See comments and answers in [this thread](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3216/customizing-c-mode-indentation-behavior-in-emacs-24-4).

Comment: @Dan *It is bound to RET.*

Comment: `RET` is the key rather than the command.  The next line will tell you the command (ie, the part in parentheses).  I'm guessing yours will say `newline-and-indent`.  You can either rebind the key (say, to `newline`), or follow the link that @legoscia posted.  This question does, indeed, look like a duplicate.

Comment: @Dan Right, the command is: `(newline &optional ARG INTERACTIVE)`. There is also the explanation: *If `electric-indent-mode' is enabled, this indents the final new line that it adds, and reindents the preceding line.*