# Turn C Electric Indentation off only for specific characters

Tags: indentation, c

Extending [Customizing c-mode indentation behavior in emacs-24.4](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3216/customizing-c-mode-indentation-behavior-in-emacs-24-4)

How can electric indentation be disabled for other specific keys without disabling the entire mode?

Specifically, how can electric indentation be turned off for `/* */` comments? Apparently disabling it for `*` does not do the job.

The following works only under some conditions.

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set-key (kbd "*") 'self-insert-command)))
```

Similarly, the following works only under some conditions

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
         (lambda ()
           (setq electric-indent-chars
                       (remq "*" electric-indent-chars))))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
         (lambda ()
           (setq electric-indent-chars
                       (remq "*" electric-indent-chars))))
```

(`?*` and `?/` also do not work)

"some conditions": comment lines following another commented line keep their non-electric indentation after typing `*`, but a comment line immediately following a closing brace has its indentation reset upon typing the `*` in `/*`

Comment: [stefan's answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3240/5296) doesn't work? (replace `?\n` with `?*`)

Comment: See updated question. I am starting to think that something else is handling indentation of comments.

Comment: Long story short, I like to indent my comments with two tabs and my tabs keep getting killed. Turning electric indentation off globally fixes that, but I like the other things electric indentation does, so I want to find a more surgical solution.

Comment: ultimately, it looks like this was a duplicate of [In emacs how to disable comment auto-indent in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061453/in-emacs-how-to-disable-comment-auto-indent-in-c-c)

Comment: Hmm, I could have sworn `electric-indent-chars` was supposed to cover other things, but actually it's only newline (maybe it's only *planned* to control other chars).